# is there a way to auto execute a predefined JavaScript through the JavaScript console of a browser when it enters a specific web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I was wondering..
I'm now getting even lazy to copy-paste my complete JS commands that I used to insert into the JavaScript console of my chrome browser.

Could there be a way to program something that will do this job for me?
what sort of programming techniques should I learn?

I would be grateful if anyone could give me some place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the Chrome team. Last year we introduced a useful feature called Snippets to the Chrome Developer Tools which should help with this exact use-case. You can find out more information about it at: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#snippets